# specified column is not in the row

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm trying to retrieve a form but every time that I try to retrieve it I keep coming across this error.

Message: Specified column "year" is not in the row

Here is my model and form code.

Model

```
class Model_Periods extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
        protected $_name = 'periods';
        protected $_primary = 'id';

        public function getPeriods()
        {
            //ZEND Distinct Quite Illusive
            $select = $this->select()
            ->from($this, array('bus_year' => new Zend_Db_Expr('DISTINCT(bus_year)')))
            ->order('bus_year DESC');

            $results = $this->fetchAll($select);
            return $results;
        }
```

Form:

```
<?php

class Form_Targets extends Zend_Form
{

public function init()
{
    $available = $this->createElement('select', 'available');

    $available->setlabel('Select a year to continue');
    $available->setAttribs(array('class' => 'print the-font'));
    $available->addDecorators(array(array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' => 'ui-select print the-font ui-print' ))));
    $available->setRequired(true);

    $pMdl = new Model_Periods();
    $periods = $pMdl->getPeriods();
    $available->addmultiOption(0, 'Year' );
    if ($periods->count() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($periods as $period)
        {
            $available->addmultiOption($period->year, $period->year);
        }
    }
    $this->addElement($available);

}

}
```

Comment: Change year with `bus_year` in line `$available->addmultiOption`.

Comment: this line  $available->addmultiOption(0, 'Year' ); and this line $available->addmultiOption($period->year, $period->year); or just the first

Comment: Just second `$available->addmultiOption($period->year, $period->year);`

Comment: Thank you I changed it with bus year for both the second ones it worked

Comment: Rikesh I'm editing old code here, why was that really happening can you explain a bit for me? You can put a valid answer and I will up vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You getting this error because you having field with name `bus_year` in your table while you using `year`. So change line

```
$available->addmultiOption($period->year, $period->year);
```

with

```
$available->addmultiOption($period->bus_year, $period->bus_year);
```